# Showing a Floating Point Number in Text

Tags: objective-c

I have a simple function that returns a floating point number as follows.

```
float offset (int secs){
    return secs/3600;
}
```

Given secs = 19800, if I use it in the following, I end up getting 5 instead of 5.5.

```
num01.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",offset(t01)]; // t01 is 19800
```

What am I doing wrong?  What can I do to set the string value of num01 (label) to 5.5 ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value is an int before it's parsed as a float.

Simply cast one of the operands as a float or use 3600.0:

```
return secs/3600.0
```

Comment: Oh, my gosh...  That's how Objective-C work?  Interesting...  I've never seen it in other development platforms.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @TBlue it's how most languages work, in this case C specifically. Expressions are evaluated before they are assigned/returned http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx

Comment: Perhaps, I just didn't know that I was making a mistake when handling floating point numbers in other languages.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code takes the result of [**integer division**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_division#Division_of_integers) and casts it to a float.  So, it goes something like this:

"Calculate the quotient of the result of dividing the integer stored in secs divided by the integer 3600.  Convert that to a floating point number and return the result."  I.e. 19,800/3600 = 5.  Convert to 5.0 and return.

Instead, use floats from the start by either changing your function to accept a float or converting (casting) your numbers to a float first:

```
return (float)sec / 3600.0;
```